# Remove duplicate element from set while insertion based on a criteria

Tags: java, set, duplicates

For a class ClassA , i have 2 attributes - X and Y
I have overridden equals method of ClassA so that equality of 2 class is found by checking attribute X.

```
ClassA {

Integer X,Y;

Integer getX(){return X;}
Integer getY(){return Y;}

boolean equals(object o){
      return getX().equals((ClassA)o).getX());
}

}
```

Now I want to remove all duplicate elements of ClassA from a List
But then if 2 elements are found duplicate  , i want to add a logic to remove the duplicate element based on Y criteria.
so basically it goes like below

```
if(A.eqauls(B)){
  remove A , if A.getY() > B.getY()
  ore remove B , if A.getY() < B.getY()
}
```

Obviously I would be trying to sort the list and see neighboring duplicate element and then removing the duplicate based on our logic.
I wonder if I can do this using sets.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Map<ClassA, ClassA> map = new HashMap();

for(ClassA elem : yourList)
{
   ClassA existing = map.get(elem);
   if(existing != null)
   {
      if(check your condition using "elem" and "existing" and getY)
      {
        continue;// don't replace the element in the map.
      }
   }
   map.put(elem, elem);
}
//map.values() will have your elements
```

You also could use `LinkedHashMap` instead if you want to preserve order of elements as in the list.

BTW, the HashSet is implemented using HashMap in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

Sets use the `equals()` method to determine if the element is already in the set or not. in other words, the first one inserted into the set will be the one you are stuck with if you just use normal insertions.

I don't think you can override this behaviour (unless you implement your own set class, where you change the add method to test equality *and* do our Y comparison too).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without breaking the general contract of `Set`, which states that `add()` will never add an element if it is equal (according to the `equals()` method) to an element already in the set. Obviously, you could *use* a `Set` if you are implementing this behaviour (you could check if you've already seen an element with a particular `X` value). A `Map` would be a slightly better choice though.

Since the behaviour is really easy to implement by sorting and looping over the list, I would use that. You don't stand to gain anything in implementation time nor in maintainability by using a `Set` (arguably you're making your code harder to read), so it really is a better option.